# I am making a 'Cipher Program' in Python and it emits strange answers

Tags: python, user-input, long-integer, encryption

I am making a Cipher program which I will later populate with different ciphers, but for now I have Morse code. I am not the best at programming yet, so the following code may seem excessive and easily broken down into a much better code.

```
import os

def c():
    os.system('cls')

doneOnce = False

while True:
    print 'Code Maker Breaker!'
    print '-------------------\n'
    if doneOnce == False:
        print 'Welcome to CMB!'
        print 'In CMB you can pick several types of codes,'
        print 'Then convert text into this code! If you want,'
        print 'You can then convert text back into this code!'
        print 'Use numbers to select different codes.\n'
        doneOnce = True
    print 'Codes! Please select with corresponding numbers.\n'
    print '1. Morse'
    code = raw_input('Enter the number for your code: ')
    c()
    if code == '1':
        print 'The Morse code should be used with spaces'
        print 'after every letter to avoid the wrong translation.\n'
        print '1. Translate from English to -- --- .-. ... .'
        print '2. Translate from -- --- .-. ... . to English'
        morse = raw_input('Enter what you want: ')
        c()
        if morse == '1':
            print 'Translating to Morse.'
            print 'Enter your English sentence'
            engtomorse = raw_input('>>> ').lower()
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('a', '.-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('b', '-...')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('c', '-.-.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('d', '-..')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('e', '.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('f', '..-.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('g', '--.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('h', '....')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('i', '..')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('j', '.---')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('k', '-.-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('l', '.-..')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('m', '--')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('n', '-.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('o', '---')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('p', '.--.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('q', '--.-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('r', '.-.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('s', '...')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('t', '-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('u', '..-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('v', '...-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('w', '.--')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('x', '-..-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('y', '-.--')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('z', '--..')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('0', '-----')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('1', '.----')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('2', '..---')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('3', '...--')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('4', '....-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('5', '.....')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('6', '-....')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('7', '--...')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('8', '---..')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('9', '----.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('.', '.-.-.-')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace(',', '--..--')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('?', '..--..')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('!', '..--.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace(':', '---...')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('"', '.-..-.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace("'", '.----.')
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('=', '-...-')
            c()
            print 'Your sentence in Morse code is', engtomorse
            print 'Press enter.'
            raw_input()
        elif morse == '2':
            pass
        else:
            print 'You entered something wrong... Go back!'
            print 'Press enter.'
            raw_input()
    else:
        print 'What?'
        print 'Press enter.'
        raw_input()
    c()
```

Okay, so that is a lot. But the part that is going wrong for my is when the user enters a sentence, then the program replaces all the letters with the Morse code equivalents. Once it is printed, I get a strange answer. For example, If I enter my sentence as an A, it will output `.-.-.--`. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please trim down your code to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It might help to explain what the "strange answer" you are referring to actually is. Anyways, I think one problem is this line: `engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('.', '.-.-.-')`, because it will replace previously created dots with this string. You might want to do that before the string has any dots.

Answer (score 7):

This will be replacing all the '.'s you have already inserted. You could try doing this replacement first

```
            engtomorse = engtomorse.replace('.', '.-.-.-')
```

you probably want to have spaces between the morse code letters too, otherwise they'll all run together

Another way to do this is to use a dictionary

```
replace_dict = {'a': '.-', 'b': '-...', ...}
engtomorse = " ".join(replace_dict[k] for k in engtomorse)
```

replacing each character like this is more efficient, and would mean you avoided that particular bug altogether

Comment: Or not using `replace` at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel so stupid now, that mistake was right in front of me!